# 1.11 Java Spigot/Bukkit programming - Save / Load HashMap into Config.yml

Tags: java, plugins, hashmap, bukkit

I counted a score in a HashMap for each Player:

```
    public Map<String, Integer> PScore = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Now I want to save and load the HashMap out and in a Config.yml. The Config is existing and in Use for a other varibales.

This were my many attempts to solve the problem:

```
public void saveHash()
{
     for (String string : PScore.keySet()) 
     {
         this.getConfig().set("score.pscore", string);
         this.saveConfig();
     }
}

public void loadHash() 
{
}
```

But in the Config I only get:

```
score:
 pscore: JackerNils
```

The loading function is empty so nothing happens of course while loading. The save and loading functions are controlled by the onEnable() and the onDisable()

//EDIT:

```
    public Map<String, Integer> PScore = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public void saveHash()
{
     List<String> s = this.getConfig().getStringList("PScore");

     for(String str : PScore.keySet())
     {
         s.add(str +  ":" + PScore.get(str));
     }
     this.getConfig().set("PScore", s);
     this.saveConfig();
}

public void loadHash() 
{
     List<String> s = this.getConfig().getStringList("PScore");

     for(String str: s)
     {
         String words[] = str.split(":");
         PScore.put(words[0], Integer.parseInt(words[1]));
     }
}
```

This method is working fine now, but look what the Config does:

```
PScore:
 - JackerNils:5
 - JackerNils:19
```

So you see? Instead of overwriting it, it repeats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the `saveConfig`, what it does is to saves and overwrites the current file which you are doing after every loop execution, resulting in only one value from the hashmap getting saved after the loop is finished. What you could do is save the config after setting all the values, like this:

```
for (String string : PScore.keySet()) 
    {
        this.getConfig().set("score.pscore", string);
    }
this.saveConfig();
```

Also keep in mind you're adding all the values into the same section in the config. Save an array instead.

Comment: Have a look on my edit! In this example it works all fine, only the saving is a bit wrong.